# How to subtract two numbers in one line in pattern?

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I've got a pretty large file(getting problems with sed and awk here).
The lines I am mainly interested in look like:

```
\# Name: name [...] [...] [here=178542..178940]
```

or

```
\# Name: name [here=reversed(10000..18899)]
```

From this line I want to extract the two numbers. The first number(x) is after the pattern `[here=` or`[here=reversed(` and stops before `..`, the second number(y) starts right after `..` and ends with `]` or `)]`.
After extracting these numbers, I want to substract y-x=z and print the `name` and 'z'.

For any hints and tips I would be pretty thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
perl -ne '/Name: (\S*) .*\[here=\D*(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/ and print $1, ": ", $3-$2, "\n";' data.txt
```

with data.txt:

```
\# Name: name [...] [...] [here=178542..178940]
\# Name: name [here=reversed(10000..18899)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner works for your example lines:

```
perl -ne '/Name: (.*?) .*\[here=.*([0-9]+)\.\.([0-9]+)/ and print "$1 ", $3-$2, "\n"'
```